# How to force main thread to wait for all its child threads finish in Haskell

Tags: multithreading, haskell

In the following Haskell code, how to force main thread to wait till all its child threads finish.

I could not able to use forkFinally as given in the section "Terminating the Program" here in this link: (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Concurrent.html).

I get desired result when using TMVar. But I want to do this with TVar.
Please help.

```
module Main
where
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.STM

type TInt = TVar Int

transTest :: TInt -> Int -> IO ()
transTest n t = do 
    atomically $ do 
        t1 <- readTVar n                    
        doSomeJob t
        t2 <- readTVar n
        writeTVar n t

doSomeJob :: Int -> STM ()
doSomeJob t = do
    x <- newTVar 0
    let l = 10^6*t
    forM_ [1..l] (\i -> do 
        writeTVar x i )            

main :: IO ()
main = do
    n <- newTVarIO 0

    let v = 5
    forkIO (transTest n v)

    let v = 3
    forkIO (transTest n v)

    let v = 7
    forkIO (transTest n v)

    let v = 1
    forkIO (transTest n v)  


    r <- atomically $ readTVar n
    putStrLn("Last updated value = " ++ (show r))
```

Comment: Use `Control.Concurrent.Thread` package which has `wait`. Standard `Control.Concurrent` threads cannot be waited for. If you want to use them, you need a separate signalling mechanism and each thread needs to explicitly report "I'm done". See http://hackage.haskell.org/package/concurrent-extra-0.3/docs/Control-Concurrent-Thread.html

Comment: Could you please give some example link? Thanks.

Comment: This problem is discussed in a 2007 Haskell Cafe thread, and you'll also find some example code there: [(link)](https://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2007-November/035329.html)

Comment: @n.m. It looks like that module went away in v-0.5 for some reason.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What I did in the past was to create a little MVar for each forked thread and then use `forkFinally` to fork the threads such that at the very end, each thread would put a dummy value into the MVar (i.e. I used the MVar as a synchronisation primitive). I could then call `takeMVar` on those MVars to wait.

I wrapped it into a little helper function:

```
forkThread :: IO () -> IO (MVar ())
forkThread proc = do
    handle <- newEmptyMVar
    _ <- forkFinally proc (\_ -> putMVar handle ())
    return handle
```

Using this, your code could be changed to something like

```
-- Fork four threads
threads <- forM [5, 3, 7, 1] (\v -> forkThread (transTest n v))

-- Wait for all of them
mapM_ takeMVar threads
```

*However*, that was before I read the (most excellent) book "Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell" by Simon Marlow, which made me aware of the [async](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.0.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html) package. The package provides an abstraction which not only takes care of all these things, so you can write just

```
-- Runs 'transTest n {5,3,7,1}' in parallel and waits for all threads
_ <- mapConcurrently (transTest n) [5, 3, 7, 1]
```

...it also takes care of things such as (asynchronous) exceptions.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's simple and indeed very useful.