# bracket doesn't release resource when inside thread

Tags: multithreading, haskell, resources

I'm having trouble with Haskell's [`bracket`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:bracket): When being run inside a forked thread (using [`forkFinally`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkFinally)) `bracket`'s second argument, the computation that releases resources is not run when the program ends.

Here's code illustrating the issue (I'm aware that in this specific case I could disable buffering to write to the file immediately):

```
import           System.IO
import           Control.Exception              ( bracket
                                                , throwTo
                                                )

import           Control.Concurrent             ( forkFinally
                                                , threadDelay
                                                )
main = do
  threadId <- forkFinally
    (writeToFile "first_file")
    (\ex -> putStrLn $ "Exception occurred: " ++ show ex)
  putStrLn "Press enter to exit"
  _ <- getLine
  putStrLn "Bye!"

writeToFile :: FilePath -> IO ()
writeToFile file = bracket
  (openFile file AppendMode)
  (\fileHandle -> do
    putStrLn $ "\nClosing handle " ++ show fileHandle
    hClose fileHandle
  )
  (\fileHandle -> mapM_ (addNrAndWait fileHandle) [1 ..])

addNrAndWait :: Handle -> Int -> IO ()
addNrAndWait fileHandle nr =
  let nrStr = show nr
  in  do
        putStrLn $ "Appending " ++ nrStr
        hPutStrLn fileHandle nrStr
        threadDelay 1000000
```

The computation that releases resources (and writes to the console) is never called:

```
putStrLn $ "\nClosing handle " ++ show fileHandle
hClose fileHandle
```

Making the program single threaded by removing the forking code from `main` gets rid of the issue and the file handle is closed when ending the program with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>:

```
main = writeToFile "first_file"
```

How do I ensure that the resource-releasing code in `bracket` is executed when using multiple threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## using [`throwTo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:throwTo)

Apparently the thread created with `forkFinally` never gets an exception thrown at and thus the resource-releasing code of `bracket` never gets executed.

We can fix this by doing this manually using `throwTo threadId ThreadKilled`:

```
import           Control.Exception              ( bracket
                                                , throwTo
                                                , AsyncException(ThreadKilled)
                                                )

import           Control.Concurrent             ( forkFinally
                                                , threadDelay
                                                )
main = do
  threadId <- forkFinally
    (writeToFile "first_file")
    (\ex -> putStrLn $ "Exception occurred: " ++ show ex)
  putStrLn "Press enter to exit"
  _ <- getLine
  throwTo threadId ThreadKilled
  putStrLn "Bye!"
```

Comment: As @ChrisSmith points out, you need to wait for the child thread to complete, or there's going to be a race condition.  (You can see the race condition by adding a short `threadDelay` before printing `"Closing handle"`.)

Answer (score 6):

The root cause of the problem here is that when `main` exits, your process just dies.  It doesn't wait on any other threads that you've created to finish.  So in your original code, you created a thread to write to the file, but it was not allowed to finish.

If you want to kill the thread but force it to clean up, then use `throwTo` as you did here.  If you want the thread to finish, you'll need to wait for that before `main` returns.  See [How to force main thread to wait for all its child threads finish in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169297/how-to-force-main-thread-to-wait-for-all-its-child-threads-finish-in-haskell)

Answer (score 2):

## using [`async`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async)

Making `getLine` block the main thread indefinitely doesn't play nice with [`nohup`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup): It will fail with

```
<stdin>: hGetLine: invalid argument (Bad file descriptor)
```

As an alternative to `getLine` and `throwTo`, you can use [`async`'s functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.2.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:withAsync):

```
import           Control.Concurrent.Async       ( withAsync, wait )

main = withAsync (writeToFile "first_file") wait
```

This enables running the program with `nohup ./theProgram-exe &`¹, for example [on a server via SSH](https://linuxhandbook.com/nohup-command/).

`async` also shines when running multiple tasks concurrently:

```
import           Control.Concurrent.Async       ( race_ )

main = race_ (writeToFile "first_file") (writeToFile "second_file")
```

The function [`race_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.2.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:race_) runs two tasks concurrently and waits until the first result arrives. With our non-terminating `writeToFile` there won't ever be a regular result, but if one of the tasks throws an exception, the other will be cancelled too. This is useful for running an HTTP and an HTTPS server simultaneously, for example.

To shut down the program cleanly — giving threads a chance to free resources in `bracket` — I send it the [SIGINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGINT) signal:

```sh
pkill --signal SIGINT theProgram-exe
```

### Handling SIGTERM

To also end threads gracefully on a [SIGTERM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGTERM), we can [install a handler](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Signals.html#v:installHandler) that will catch the signal:

```
import           Control.Concurrent.Async       ( withAsync
                                                , wait
                                                , cancel
                                                , Async
                                                )
import           System.Posix.Signals

main = withAsync
  (writeToFile "first_file")
  (\asy -> do
    cancelOnSigTerm asy
    wait asy
  )

cancelOnSigTerm :: Async a -> IO Handler
cancelOnSigTerm asy = installHandler
  sigTERM
  (Catch $ do
    putStrLn "Caught SIGTERM"
    -- Throws an AsyncCancelled exception to the forked thread, allowing
    -- it to release resources via bracket
    cancel asy
  )
  Nothing
```

Now, our program will release its resources in `bracket` when receiving SIGTERM:

```sh
pkill theProgram-exe
```

Here's the equivalent for two concurrent tasks supporting SIGTERM:

```
import           Control.Concurrent.Async       ( withAsync
                                                , wait
                                                , cancel
                                                , Async
                                                , waitEither_
                                                )
import           System.Posix.Signals

main = raceWith_ cancelOnSigTerm
                 (writeToFile "first_file")
                 (writeToFile "second_file")

raceWith_ :: (Async a -> IO b) -> IO a -> IO a -> IO ()
raceWith_ f left right = withAsync left $ \a -> withAsync right $ \b -> do
  f a
  f b
  waitEither_ a b
```

For more on the topic of asynchronous Haskell, have a peek at [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/parallel-and-concurrent/9781449335939/) by Simon Marlow.

---

¹<sub>Call `stack build` to get an executable at, for example, `.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/theProgram-exe/theProgram-exe`. You can get the path of this directory with `stack path --local-install-root`.</sub>